# Will an electric arc occur if there is a large enough resistor between voltage source terminals?

Tags: voltage-divider, high-voltage, arc

I want to create a multi select voltage divider from high voltage (1-2kV), but the switch (50V rated) is not rated for high voltage.

Should I worry about an arc being created if I have a 10MOhm resistor between the switch and the voltage terminals?
(R1 and R2 from schematic are rated for high voltage - 2kV)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmH9Dz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Arc will probably self-extinguish pretty fast with only 0.1mA DC available. So if the switch is at least 350V AC rated (500V peak) this may be OK despite a 50V DC rating. Otherwise ... rethink the design.

Answer (score 2):

Arcing probably not, due to 10M Source impedance. But the switch rating is an issue. If it is a relay switch, it might actually still hold even at 500 V (again because no arcing due to 10 M source impedance). If it is a MOSFET switch, it might conduct in "avalanche" mode, but probably not get destroyed due to the small current.

Edit: as the bottom contact of the switch will remain closed, switch leakage conduction will not put your downstream nodes at high potential.